# Referencing equations with custom tags still uses numbering with babel?

Tags: equations, cross-referencing, fontspec, babel, hebrew

I use `babel` with `luatex` to make Hebrew documents and I encountered a weird issue with this sample code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\PassOptionsToPackage{no-math}{fontspec}

\usepackage[bidi=basic, layout=tabular]{babel}

\babelprovide[main, import, alph=letters, Alph=letters]{hebrew}
\babelprovide[import]{english}

\babelfont[hebrew]{rm}{Calibri}
\babelfont[hebrew]{sf}{Calibri}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{Pythagoras}
a^2 + b^2 = c^2 \tag{\textasteriskcentered}
\end{equation}
משפט פיתגורס \eqref{Pythagoras}.
\end{document}
```

As you can see, I have a custom tag for the equation `(*)`. When I compile the code, the equation is displayed correctly with the `(*)` tag, but the reference on the next line is displayed as `(1)`:
[image]

Another weird, but not as important, issue I just noticed is that it uses a regular asterisk instead of `\textasteriskcentered`. How can I fix it to use `\textasteriskcentered`? But more importantly, how can I make it use the custom tag for both the equation and the references?

Comment: Looks like a bug in babel. I don't currently see any easy fix for that, and in fact found another bug when I tried to solve this one... Can you open a bug ticket at github?

Comment: @UdiFogiel I opened an issue on [github](https://github.com/latex3/babel/issues/260). I hope a solution will be found soon.